# Corona SDK - Handling Touch Events in Lua

Tags: lua, touch, coronasdk

I am working on a simple app in Lua to get a better feel for the Corona SDK: a red ball bounces around the screen and switches directions once the user touches it. However, whenever I click on the ball in the Corona Simulator, the touch event gets called more than just once. Here is my code:

```
local xdirection,ydirection = 1,1
local xpos,ypos = display.contentWidth*0.5,display.contentHeight*0.5
local circle = display.newCircle( xpos, ypos, 20 );
circle:setFillColor(255,0,0,255);

local x_speed = 5
local y_speed = 5 

local function animate(event)
    xpos = xpos + ( x_speed * xdirection );
    ypos = ypos + ( y_speed * ydirection );

    if (xpos > display.contentWidth - 20 or xpos < 20) then
            xdirection = xdirection * -1;
    end
    if (ypos > display.contentHeight - 20 or ypos < 20) then
            ydirection = ydirection * -1;
    end

    circle:translate( xpos - circle.x, ypos - circle.y)
end

local function switch(event)
    xdirection = xdirection * -1;
    ydirection = ydirection * -1;
    print "Switched!"
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", animate );
circle:addEventListener("touch",switch);
```

Every time I click on the ball in the simulator, "Switched!" gets printed more than once. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "touch" event is called twice, at the beginning and at the end of the touch event. Try printing event.phase at your switch function.

You should be using:

```
circle:addEventListener("tap",switch);
```

Answer (score 3):

when you you use on touch event there will be three event phase trigger the

```
began, moved, ended
```

if you want to trigger one phase in an event on touch put this on your code

```
local function switch(event)
    if (event.phase == "ended") then
    xdirection = xdirection * -1;
    ydirection = ydirection * -1;
    print "Switched!"
    end
end
```